# mod_rewrite error

Tags: mod-rewrite

Using this rewrite rule is giving me a 500.  What is wrong with my syntax?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^microsites/(.*)$ /microsites/index.php?uID=$1 [L]
```

What I want to do is silently write   http://site.com/microsites/anythingatall to http://site.com/microsites/index.php?uID=anythingatall

Edit:  the following works and does not throw an error

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9])$ /microsites/index.php?uID=$1 [L]
```

// end edit

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: What does the rewrite.log say?

Comment: Hi Taylor,  for kicks I added RewriteLog "/var/www/vhosts/site.com/rewrite.log" but no logging was done.  Seems unlikely that an htaccess causing an internal error would be able to log the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is that `microsites/index.php` is also matched by `^microsites/(.*)$`. Exclude your destination and it should work:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=index.php
RewriteRule ^microsites/(.*)$ /microsites/index.php?uID=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This instead:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /microsites/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /microsites/index.php?uID=$1 [L]
```

It's been awhile, but I believe you need to ensure your base takes care of any actual folder names unless you're going to use them as pieces of your replacement value.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  When I replace my rule for yours I get the internal server error; if I comment out just the rule  like #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /microsites/index.php?uID=$1 [L]  the error goes away same as with my rule.

Comment: However the following works and does not throw and error?!  RewriteRule ^([0-9])$ /microsites/index.php?uID=$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

Check your rewrite log.  I think you're ending up in a rewrite loop, as `^microsites/(.*)$` is matched by the URL you're redirecting to (`/microsites/index.php?uID=$1`) so it continues to cycle until your max number of internal redirects is met (by default 10)

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^microsites/([^\.\?]+)$ /microsites/index.php?uID=$1 [L]
```

which means (in pseudo-code)

```
if we found a "microsites/" at the beginning
and there are no "." or "?" characters, store this value in $1
then redirect to /microsites/index.php?uID=$1
```

so the second time around, it will see you've already done the redirect and not loop forever